# Computing the volume of this weird object,

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, volume

Let $f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f(-1) = f(1) = 0$ and $0<f(x)\le 1$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$.  Let $S$ be the surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ obtained by revolving the curve $y=f(x)$ around the $x$-axis and $V$ the volume inside $S$.  Determine the volume of the object obtained by removing this volume $V$ from the inside of the sphere of radius $2$ centered at $0$.

Edit: I think evgeny's hint (see below) in the comments is a good one to go with, so I computed the volume V of the surface S with triple integration of the 1-function, with

$-1 \le x \le 1$

$-1 \le z \le 1$

-min{f(x), $\sqrt(1-x^2)$} $\le y \le$ +min{f(x), $\sqrt{1-x^2}$},

as my bounds of integration.

The volume of the object is then $\frac {32\pi}{3}$ - 8*min{f(x), $\sqrt{1-x^2}$}.

Feel free to comment on this answer or offer another solution.  My only concern is that we don't seem to have used the $C^1$ condition on f.  (Unless it was given primarily so that we know the function is smooth enough from x=-1 to x=1, e.g., no sharp corners along the curve.)

Comment: Do you expect the answer is independent of $f$?  Because this certainly isn't the case:  If $f$ satisfies the required conditions, then so does $\lambda \times f$ for $0 < \lambda < 1$, and the volume generated by $\lambda \times f$ differs from the volume generated by $f$.

Comment: good point, @Strants ... hmm ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have $$V=\pi \int_{-1}^1 f^2(x)dx$$ This equation is coming from the computation of the volume in cylindrical coordinates $$V=\int\int\int_V dxdydz=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{2 \pi}\int_0^{f(x)} r dx d\theta dr$$

Now, the issue is that the object limited by the surface $S$ might not be included in the sphere of radius equal to $2$ and centered at the origin.

Comment: @Rogelio. That condition is not sufficient to have the object limited by the surface $S$ included in the sphere. If the function $f$ is close to a square in particular.

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, can you explain your hint a bit more?  Where is this equation coming from?  Why $f^2$ in the integrand?  Thanks,

Comment: You get this equation by using cylindrical coordinates,

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: in the interval $[-1,1]$ the sphere of radius $2$ has cylindric radius $\ge\sqrt{3} > 1$. Since the function is restricted to be $\le 1$, the surface clearly is completely inside the sphere.

Comment: To find the volume of inner part we can take $\min \lbrace f(x), \sqrt{1-x^2} \rbrace$ as the upper limit of innermost integral.

Comment: Very cool, @evgeny - thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, I just want to think about this problem once more before moving on - please see my edited post above.  You're hint is the one to go with, I think - but I am concerned that we did not use the $C^1$ condition on f.  Thanks,

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, I think your hint only works if f traces out a rectangular curve, which, as it revolves around the x-axis, creates a cylindrical surface.  But this is not possible, I think, in the sense that f cannot trace out a rectangle - doing so would make f multi-valued at two points, namely at x = -1 and x = 1, which makes f not even a *function*.  But, feel free to clarify your hint, if you were thinking of something entirely different from my thoughts.  Thanks,

Comment: (also, a rectangular curve is not $C^1$, let alone smooth, because of the two upper corners.)

Comment: I'd recommend you to stick to @mathcounterexamples.net answer. He is absolutely right about cylindrical coordinates because it's the simplest method for solids of revolution. I can't say that I understand your explanation about rectangular curve.

Comment: Hi @evgeny - I didn't see this comment until early this morning.  So I thought about it again, and yes, you are absolutely right!! :-)  I will re-do this problem now to make sure I have it right. Thanks so much for getting back to me.  Have a great day!

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, I finally understand your hint now! Thanks so much :-)  it took me awhile :-( I've found that too much focus on the upper level proof-based courses, e.g., real / complex analysis, makes me forget the tricky multivariable integration problems that we used to do every night in our calculus courses.  Have a great day!

Comment: Actually, @mathcounterexamples.net, if you would like to comment further on this problem, perhaps you can comment on whether we actually used the $C^1$ condition on f.  It seems to have been included primarily so that we don't have to worry about any curves with corners being traced out.  I ask because, I feel that continuity alone, and not differentiability, let alone f being of class $C^1$ , is enough for us to integrate and compute the volumes of both objects.  Thanks,

Comment: I do agree that $f$ continuity would be enough.

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem and just noticed you had wrote back in the comments -- thanks so much @mathcounterexamples.net :-)